# Load next page after filter redirect & login

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I've got two servlets (Java 8, Tomcat 8.5):

`servlet1` loads an html page with a form (with radio buttons). Pressing the "Send" button loads `servlet2`, which then displays a custom message depending on which radio button was selected.

This works, so I also added a filter (according to the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)) that redirects you to the login page if there's no active session, when the "Send" button is clicked.

Filter and `\login` servlet in the "web.xml":

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bla/*</url-pattern> <!-- Pressing the "Send" button loads "/bla" -->
</filter-mapping>
```

The login form ("Login.html"):

```
<form action="login">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Pressing the "Login" button loads the `\login` servlet to verify the username/password:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/html/Login.html").include(request, response);
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    
    if(user!=null && !user.isEmpty() && pass!=null && !pass.isEmpty()) {
        //Verify user/pw here
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(); //create new session
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
    } else {
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Some error message!</p>");
    }
}
```

The question I'm currently failing to answer: How do I load `servlet2` or whatever page should have been loaded (before the filter intervened) after pressing the "Login" button and verifying that the login details are correct?